# Is it possible to run locally default GitHub Codespaces image locally?

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer

As I don't have access to Github Codespaces and I'm not the type of person to pay for Github Teams only for this... is it possible to run `mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/universal:2.0.9-linux` locally with docker?

I tried to use steps in `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/codespaces-linux` to copy `.devcontainer` folder to my project folder, but when I try to use `Remote-Containers: Reopen Folder in Container` it stops with error:

```
[2022-09-05T22:07:51.999Z] Stop (218 ms): Run: docker inspect --type container 2e252fbefb8fa27f8e4d527747cb5da095103cd894f904fd94004f0fdbc8df93
[2022-09-05T22:07:51.999Z] Stop (218 ms): Inspecting container
[2022-09-05T22:07:51.999Z] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.002Z] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.016Z] Stop (17 ms): Run in container: /bin/sh
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.016Z] Shell server terminated (code: 1, signal: null)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.016Z] Error response from daemon: Container 2e252fbefb8fa27f8e4d527747cb5da095103cd894f904fd94004f0fdbc8df93 is not running
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.016Z] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.016Z] Stdin closed!
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z] Error: An error occurred setting up the container.
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z]     at SF (/home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:257:2186)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z]     at pb (/home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:257:2124)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z]     at async DF (/home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:263:2006)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z]     at async to (/home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:263:3110)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.017Z]     at async Ak (/home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:383:8108)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.018Z]     at async Ok (/home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:383:7864)
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.021Z] Stop (736 ms): Run: /opt/visual-studio-code/code --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/randomperson/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /home/randomperson/Documents/Github/Bob --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/randomperson/Documents/Github/Bob --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/randomperson/Documents/Github/Bob/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.021Z] Exit code 1
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.025Z] Command failed: /opt/visual-studio-code/code --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node /home/randomperson/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.251.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/randomperson/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --workspace-folder /home/randomperson/Documents/Github/Bob --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/randomperson/Documents/Github/Bob --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/randomperson/Documents/Github/Bob/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-09-05T22:07:52.025Z] Exit code 1
```

Is there maybe an image with a specific tag that can be self-hosted or my machine is just too slow for this.